# VSCode keeps switching my cursor focus to the output panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have plugins running on file save, and every time I save a file, my cursor is switched into the console for some reason. How to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the settings sync extension:

https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/blob/eb332ba5e8180680e613e94be89119119c5638d1/src/sync.ts#L595-L597

VS Code now has a setting sync feature built-in: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

I was having this problem (that's how I got here) and can confirm that after disabling the extension, the problem disappeared. Start using the VS Code built-in sync feature.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149054#issuecomment-1121133365